# Unable to send email to other domains using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

Please look at the following code:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTP_SERVER_USERNAME, SMTP_SERVER_PASSWORD);
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.Host = SMTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME;
client.Port = 587;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Timeout = 4000;

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Body = "Test";
message.From = new MailAddress(MY_OWN_ADDRESS);
message.ReplyToList.Add(message.From);
message.Sender = message.From;
message.Subject = SUBJECT_LINE;
message.To.Add(RECIPIENT_ADDRESS);
```

I am currently unable to use it to send emails. The code resides in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the old ASPX engine. It runs on an IIS7 server with ASP.NET 4.0 in Integrated Pipeline mode.

When this code is run, one of twothings happens:

- If RECIPIENT_ADDRESS is the equal to MY_OWN_ADDRESS, or another email address on my domain, the email sends and all is well.
- However, if RECIPIENT_ADDRESS is any email address, working or otherwise, on another server such as gmail, an exception occurs during SmtpClient.Send:

**Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication is required for relay**

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication is required for relay

Comment: Why are `message.From` and `message.Sender` different?

Comment: What is the value of SMTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME, and where in your network is that server located?

Comment: @Joe, unless I'm mistaken, they aren't. message.From, message.Sender, and message.ReplyTo all should have the same value.

Comment: @Jordan, the value is mail.mydomainname.com, and it's a shared hosting provider that I purchase service from.

Comment: @Kivin, Wow it's late, sorry! One more question, is RECIPIENT_ADDRESS a MailAddress object?

Comment: @Joe, no it isn't. It's a string containing the email address.

Comment: @Joe, while waiting for a response I wrapped RECIPIENT_ADDRESS in a MailAddress object. Strangely, the problem is now solved. I wish I knew why. In any case, if you want to put that down as an actual answer, I'd be happy to mark it accepted so you can get credit and others can use it.

Comment: @Kivin, thanks I added my answer. I didn't try to make it sound like I knew what I was talking about, but I want that if someone search for this question could find a clear solution. I'm glad we found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your `message.To.Add(RECIPIENT_ADDRESS)` might have been a string. I've had issues with this in the past. Wrap it in a `MailAddress` object and it should work.