# Sending emails using VB code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, webforms, smtp

Not sure if this question has been asked elsewhere...

For a website project that I'm working on, I created an ASPX web form that will send an email containing the contents of the form on button click. I tried it and it worked when I'm using the Yahoo SMTP server and testing using my personal Yahoo email address (+ specifying the username and password).

However, it wouldn't work when I'm using the SMTP server for mail messages for the website (after I've created a new admin email account in the website).

The website is up and running and I'm able to send an email to the website's admin email account (through Yahoo) but just not when sending through the ASPX web form.

Here is the code for using the Yahoo SMTP server and it works fine:

```
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username@yahoo.com", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = "25"
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
    mail.From = New MailAddress("username@yahoo.com")
    mail.To.Add("username@yahoo.com")
    mail.Subject = "RE: Message Subject"
    mail.Body = "Message goes here."
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Now, here is the code for using my website's SMTP server which doesn't work:

```
    SmtpServer.Port = "25"
    SmtpServer.Host = "127.0.0.1"
    mail.From = New MailAddress("admin@awesomewebsite.org.au")
    mail.To.Add("admin@awesomewebsite.org.au")
    mail.Subject = "RE: Message Subject"
    mail.Body = "Message goes here."
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

These are the correct port and host numbers given by the web hosting company that hosts the website. They also said that username and password are not needed. I also tried appending this to the beginning of the code but it still wouldn't work:

```
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential()
```

or even

```
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
```

I really don't know what to do. Please help this newbie out. Any response is appreciated.

By the way, the error message that I get when I test this out appears in a message box: "Failure sending mail."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an email account in your web site and use those credentials to send the mail just as you did with yahoo (This can be done in your admin portal of the website but some hosting providers will charge you separately for the email service). Further more the correct smtp server is also should be given, that depends on your hosting provider. You can get that information from your hosting provider. 127.0.0.1 will not work here anyway.

Comment: I changed 127.0.0.1 (even though this was what they had given me) to the mail server of the website: 198.154.99.8. I also added the username and password for the credentials. Now I get a lovely new error message. "Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Authentication is required for relay."

Comment: Did you create the mail address in your web site?

Comment: Yes I did. I am also able to access this mail address and see the test email that I sent from my Yahoo email.

Comment: Did you give the correct credentials like this. smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "yourPassword")

Comment: I changed it now to that but it still gives the same "Mailbox unavailable" error message like before.

Comment: Can you check this if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659210/unable-to-send-email-to-other-domains-using-system-net-mail-smtpclient

Comment: This wasn't the problem. I was able to fix it up though and make it work. Setting the credentials correctly as: System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password") is part of the solution though. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are welcome and if you can post the actual answer, that will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import 'System.Net.Mail'.
Completed code is shown below:

```
    Dim SmtpServer As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    Dim mail As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
    SmtpServer.Host = "198.154.99.8"
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New   System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@awesomewebsite.org.au", "password")

    mail.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("admin@awesomewebsite.org.au")
    mail.To.Add("admin@awesomewebsite.org.au")
    mail.Subject = "RE: Message Subject"
    mail.Body = "Message goes here."

    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```